# The maximum size for file that can be read in .net

Tags: c#, .net

What's the maximum size of file that can be read in .net Framework ?

It's the long(Int64) max because it's the type of the offset in the Seek method in all reader ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is "undefined" by the language specification.

The seek offset is based of an origin, so you can seek a file larger long max.  You just can't seek from the file start.  Also, the file object does not have to support seek to be read.  There's more info in the [FileStream.Seek Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx)

Maybe someone else knows better, but I don't believe there's a maximum file size defined.  You'll be constrained by what you do with the data read from the filesystem ( e.g. running out of memory to store it, etc. )

Answer (score 4):

It is only constrained by the file system.  Seek() isn't a required function, C/C++ programmers have dealt with their fseek()'s limit of 2 gigabytes for a long time.  Lots of file access is sequential.  The .NET version is however going to work without trouble for a while though, the current Windows file system (NTFS version 6) limits the file size to 17,592,185,978,880 bytes, well south of 2^63 - 1.

Answer (score 1):

That would be my guess, but there are other constraints, such as the file size imposed by the file system.  On NTFS it is 2 Terabytes, but on FAT32 it is 4GB minus 2 Bytes, for example.

Comment: I always thought the file size limit on FAT32 was 2^32 - 1 bytes? Do you have a source for the 2Gb limit?

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical maximum (not taking the file system limitations into account) is `Int64.MaxValue`, as you had guessed. I'm not sure what happens if you read a file longer than that, but it seems very unlikely ;)

Comment: Only 8388608 tebibyte... a modest limit ;)